# MongoDB Atlas very slow to insert many

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm testing out the MongoDB atlas and compared to how my code is running in Docker on the local network something doesn't feel right.

Here is a log of my docker insert times;

```
Called Add for INInvoiceData
Adding 511 for INInvoiceData
Added
Time elapsed: 00:00:02
Finished add/update for INInvoiceData
Called Add for OEOrderData
Adding 427 for OEOrderData
Added
Time elapsed: 00:00:01
Finished add/update for OEOrderData
Total Time elapsed: 00:01:12
```

Here is using the paid 2GB cluster

```
Logged in
Called Add for INInvoiceData
Adding 511 for INInvoiceData
Added
Time elapsed: 00:00:59
Finished add/update for INInvoiceData
Called Add for OEOrderData
Adding 427 for OEOrderData
Added
Time elapsed: 00:00:48
Finished add/update for OEOrderData
Time elapsed: 00:03:00
```

I'm in New Zealand and the database is in Oregon(AWS) in the USA. I am using InsertMany() to add around 500 documents.

The documents average around 11kb each and once the collections are done it's only 5.9mb! I have 500mb upload on the connection i'm currently on.

Here is an example of the code

```
    static void AddMongo(IMongoDatabase MongoDB, List<DocumentUpdate> documents, string objectName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Called Add for {objectName}");
        var collection = MongoDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(objectName);
        // initialise write model to hold list of our upsert tasks
        List<BsonDocument> bsonList = new List<BsonDocument>();
        Console.WriteLine($"Adding {documents.Count} for {objectName}");

        // Create new stopwatch.
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        // Begin timing.
        stopwatch.Start();

        // Loop docs and add our PK
        for (var i = 0; i < documents.Count; i++)
        {
            var bsonDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(documents[i].json);
            bsonDoc["_id"] = documents[i].keyValue;
            bsonList.Add(bsonDoc);
        };

        collection.InsertMany(bsonList);

        Console.WriteLine("Added");
        // Stop.
        stopwatch.Stop();

        // Write hours, minutes and seconds.
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

After doing some tweaking I can dring this down by inserting one in a loop. However this isn't ideal.

```
    static void AddMongo(IMongoDatabase MongoDB, List<DocumentUpdate> documents, string objectName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Called Add for {objectName}");
        var collection = MongoDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(objectName);
        // initialise write model to hold list of our upsert tasks
        List<BsonDocument> bsonList = new List<BsonDocument>();
        Console.WriteLine($"Adding {documents.Count} for {objectName}");

        // Create new stopwatch.
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        // Begin timing.
        stopwatch.Start();

        // Loop docs and add our PK
        for (var i = 0; i < documents.Count; i++)
        {
            var bsonDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(documents[i].json);
            bsonDoc["_id"] = documents[i].keyValue;
            collection.InsertOneAsync(bsonDoc);
            //bsonList.Add(bsonDoc);
        };

        //collection.InsertMany(bsonList);

        Console.WriteLine("Added");
        // Stop.
        stopwatch.Stop();

        // Write hours, minutes and seconds.
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to contact Atlas support, since they'll have more access to insights to what happened. There should be a button marked "Support" on the Atlas interface.

Comment: The comparison is not adequate, in the second example you are not awaiting the InsertOneAsync so you do not know when it is completed. So I would guess that reaching the goal of inserting the documents is actually much slower in that case. Have you tested the InsertMany locally as well?

Comment: @SJFJ If I run InsertMany locally it inserts 500+ documents in a couple of seconds which is what I would expect.

Comment: @Adam91Holt did you get any response? How did you increase your insert rate?

Comment: @ALH - I moved the node much closer to where I am. The latency was a killer from memory!

Comment: shouldn't the distance of your database from your app be the first point of your consideration?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Sure, but I was using the free atlas cluster and they didn't have the Sydney region free at the time

Comment: ic, because question mentioned 'paid 2gb cluster'.